# Moving SQL Server filestream data to AWS S3

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have a SQL Server Database (with filestream) with few TB of unstructured data. I want to move all of those data to AWS S3 in a bucket as a file. From what I have heard AWS Glue will help with that and I don't have to worry about scaling out.

I am new to AWS Glue so I am not sure how to do this. 
So far I have been able to create connection and run the crawler, which created a database schema for me. Then, I created a job that pulled the data from SQL Server to S3 bucket. All the data are in JSON format in multiple files.

Now, how do I put binary unstructured data as a file in S3 bucket?

Am I going the wrong path by using Glue? I would really appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: Could you clarify the issue? Do you want to produce one single JSON file or do you want to produce a SQL backup file/binary file?

Comment: Binary file. I mean save varbinary(max) data as a file in S3.